# does Motorola EMDK 2.8 for .net supports Motorola MC3090Z RFID

Tags: motorola-emdk

we have developed a program on Motorola's EMDK 2.8 for .net for Motorola MC3090G and it worked just fine, but when running on MC3090Z it did not work and we wonder if the EMDK 2.8 for .net supports the MC3090Z RFID.

Answer (score 1):

For the device MC3090Z, the only EMDK one can use is the 2.5 for .NET, from EMDK 2.6 and upwards only compatible with MC3190Z

Answer (score 0):

Actually if you have your MC3090Z up to date with the correct .Net CF and OS, and current DLLs installed, then you'll be able to develop many type of software using any version of EMDK for .Net. But there are some specific APIs and DLLs depending on hardware requirements you won't be able to use. In order to help a little bit with documentation you may check these links out from official Motorola website:

[a link to EMDK for .Net filtered search](https://portal.motorolasolutions.com/Support/US-EN/Search?searchType=simple&searchTerm=emdk%for%.net)

Enter on current v2.5 and further versions and go to the Release Notes link on Public Software section. You'll notice in the table from Device Compatibility section the devices approved for each version which means best compatible rates between hardware and software.

I think you should know also the best way to test this is deploying directly to your Mobile device from Visual Studio IDE

Hope this may be usefull